# problem with displaying jLabel Icon inside JAR File on another machine

Tags: java, image, jar, icons, embedded-resource

I am building a normal Java project, which I need to deploy it as a JAR app on Windows. This type of app is StandAlone software, which loads everything from the machine I am using while building this app. It contains a logo which I really need to make visible. It works perfectly on my machine because it always finds the directory which contains this logo on my PC, but I need a method in order to make this logo built inside my app or can load it from the project folder even if I share this folder with other machines to run my app. So I want to make this logo visible for every machine runs my app, no matter where the folder locates in other machines. I am using Netbeans 1.8

Thanks in advance :)

[image]

Comment: Put the image inside your .jar file, and load it using [Class.getResource](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: Could you please write the steps how to do that, especially wih class.getResource thing. I am new in porgramming.

Comment: *"the steps how to do that"* There's really only one step, where an URL is obtained, pointing to the resource. See the [info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for embedded resources.

Answer (score 0):

By a logo ... do you mean an Icon in the upper corner of your Window? I'll use an example of doing that from inside of an executable jar. However, the concept is similar for reading any resource you want to package inside of your jar.

There are two key concepts here that differ from just reading ordinary files when you aren't running from inside of a jar. Things work differently.

```
java.awt.Image frameImage = new javax.swing.ImageIcon(
    getClass().getResource("/LotsaIcon.jpg")
).getImage();
```

Notice how instead of giving paths to files, we are loading this resource as a stream (if it's location is inside of the jar file.)

Relative paths are required here, relative to the location of your file in the jar in relation to the root where the java 'main' is executing from. What this means, is that for a file located in the same directory as the java is being executed from, it needs the slash in front of the filename. Very important. Outside of a jar you wouldn't need that. Inside a jar, that preceding slash needs to be there ... to say here, in this relative directory. A relative path, not an absolute one ... relative to where the java code is being run from inside the jar.

A third thing is ... are you using maven? If so, to get your resource into the jar when you build your project you would need to tell maven that in your POM file.

```
        <resources>
          <resource>
            <directory>src/my-resources</directory>
            <includes>
              <include>**/*.txt</include>
              <include>**/*.jpg</include>
            </includes>
          </resource>
        </resources>



    </build>
```

... somewhere before that last /build in your POM.

Otherwise ... it won't even go into your jar. Then, place the resource into the folder you see in that POM directive. It's there in your project src/my-resources

Maven moves it around, does things, and places it into your jar for you at the root directory when it makes the executable jar ... at the root level. That's why the relative path / in fron of my file. If I had placed it inside of a bunch of folders under that src/my-resources directory ... I would have to precede my filename with that relative path, so that the program knew where in src/my-resources to look ... deeper.

I just use the root though.

I hope that gets you going. Sometimes, for some things, getResource doesn't cut it, and you need to switch to using getResourceAsStream instead. Depends what you're doing.

I hope this gives you somewhere to start. A jar is a different environment from being out on the disk looking at absolute paths to places. There is a methodology to it. You're not looking out at a file system anymore; you're looking inside the jar for it, there is no file system, or C:. You're in a fishbowl. You need to find your resource there in the fishbowl too, not out on a file system. And you have to make sure your file gets put into the fishbowl with you when you build your project as well ... or it isn't even there to find in the first place. And don't forget that relative path in your code ... the preceding slash that you wouldn't need out on the regular file system.

Good luck!

Comment: I'll add, that I assumed you were using an IDE and something like Maven. If you're doing this by hand on the command line, you have to write a manifest and tell the jar you're putting your resource into it, and pack that into the jar too when you compress it; instructions. I'm assuming you're letting an IDE handle that for you. I sure do.